# Regex - Replace if number not equal debug issue

Tags: regex, preg-replace, regex-negation

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? This is my example data:

```
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=123
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=494
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=527
```

I need to search for `Itemid` different to `527`, and replace the number to `494`. This is my code:

```
$pattern = '/(.*)(Itemid=)(?!527)([1-9]*)/';
$replacement = "494";
$row->text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1'.'$2'.$replacement, $row->text);
```

And I receive something like this

```
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&94=
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&94=
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=527
```

This doesn't work properly on [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com),  it does (with `g` flag though).

Now if I add something after the second expression like this:

```
$row->text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1'.'$2'."WTF?".$replacement, $row->text);
```

Then it starts to look proper... but there is this unneeded WTF inside a link:

```
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=WTF?494
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=WTF?494
/docman/?view=document&alias=690-uchwala-rady-miasta-nr-xv-100-2015-zmieniajaca-uchwale-nr-xxxiii-151-2012&category_slug=gminne-programy-i-strategie&Itemid=527
```

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong and how can I debug this? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$row->text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1'.'${2}'.$replacement, $row->text);
```

The reason your previous code was not working was because it was joining `$2` and the `494`, so rather than looking for **Capture Group #2**, it  was looking for **Capture Group #2494** (the `4` is the first digit of `494`). So to avoid the issue, add `{}` around the number so it sees the `494` separate to the `2`

If you look at this <kbd>[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/sG2bM7/1)</kbd> demo, you can see the error inside the **Substitute** section, highlighted in red

If you look at the new <kbd>[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/sG2bM7/2)</kbd> demo, you can see the new Substitute working

---

Also, you can change your RegEx to be shorter and more efficient:

```
(.*Itemid=)(?!527)(\d*)
```

Combine `(.*)(Itemid=)` into `(.*Itemid=)`. This means your Substituion can become this, `${1}494`

Also use `\d` to select a digit, rather than `[1-9]` (unless you do not want `0` to be included, but that is something else you may have in your ID that you missed in your RegEx)

<kbd>[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aQ6qQ4/1)</kbd>

---

Then, you could make it safer, so I would suggest the following final RegEx and Substitution:

```
(.*Itemid=)(?!527$)(\d*)(.*)
${1}494$3
```

This allows for URL variables after the `Itemid`, like this, `...&Itemid=494&Foo=Bar`

It also stops IDs like `&Itemid=5279` from not being selected

<kbd>[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aZ4hS6/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank You soo much Druzion, I'll accept the @Wiktor answer as he was first, if this is ok with You? :)

Comment: @ThomasKolasa No problem! I don't mind who's answer you mark as accepted, though naturally I would prefer mine `;)`, so go ahead and accept his.

Comment: Wow dude! That is the best answer I did ever get on stack :o :D Btw. After adding the "$" in pattern = '/(.*Itemid=)(?!527$)(\d*)(.*)/'; it also matches the current 527 itemid

Comment: @ThomasKolasa Thank you! I try to put a lot of info into my answers to cover all possible scenarios. Also, it works in the [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP1sH4/1)...? It does not match the `527`? Make sure you are using the **Global** (`g`) and **Multiline** (`m`) flags

Comment: It was about the m flag. After changing it to the: $row->text = preg_replace($pattern.'m', '${1}'.$replacement.'$3', $row->text); everything works. Thanks for Your awesome answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the braces to define the capture group ID in an *unambiguous* manner:

```
$row->text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1'.'${2}'.$replacement, $row->text);
                                           ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV8aO2/4)

Since the `$replacement` starts with a digit, the regex engine is looking for a capture group #24 value (`$24` is parsed as the 24th capturing group). To avoid that, use braces around the group ID after `$` in the replacement pattern. Or use named captures to avoid the issue altogether.

I also suggest adding `$` after  `527` in the pattern (`(?!527$)`) so as not to exclude IDs that start with `527`. And surely you can merge the first 2 groups into one and use `[0-9]` instead of `[1-9]` to match IDs like `206` where a `0` can appear inside, and remove the unnecessary capturing group from `[0-9]*`:

```
(.*Itemid=)(?!527$)[0-9]*
                 ^
```

and replace with  `'${1}'.$replacement`.

Comment: yeap this was the mistake I made. Also adding the $ in the   $pattern = '/(.*)(Itemid=)(?!527$)([1-9]*)/'; seems to make match with 527. Maybe I should add a multiline flag? Must check it out. Thank You Wiktor.

Comment: @ThomasKolasa: What do you mean *seems to make match with 527*? It is clear from my demo that the lines with `Itemid=527` at the end are not matched. If you do not use `$`, then, `5277` will also fail to match. Compare [this](https://regex101.com/r/nK1cM5/1) to [that](https://regex101.com/r/nK1cM5/2) patterns.

Comment: Ok, there are other issues in your pattern that Druzion focuses your attention.

Comment: I was missing the m flag. Thank You @Wiktor for Your time.